# Enable /oauth/token endpoint springdoc-openapi-ui

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm upgrading from `springfox-swagger2` to `springdoc-openapi-ui`. I use the swagger definitions on the frontend to autogenerate types. The `/oauth/token` endpoint is missing in `springdoc-openapi-ui`. This is my config:

```
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "title",
description = "description", version = "v1"))
@SecurityScheme(name = "security_auth", type = SecuritySchemeType.OAUTH2,
flows = @OAuthFlows(password = @OAuthFlow(
        authorizationUrl = "${oauth.auth.url}",
        tokenUrl = "${oauth.auth.url}/oauth/token", refreshUrl = "${oauth.auth.url}",
        scopes = {@OAuthScope(name = "all", description = "all scope")})))
public class OpenApiConfig {}
```

I have an auth server thats part of the same application (shares the same `pom.xml` with my resource server. The Auth Server is `spring-security-oauth2` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public AuthorizationServerConfiguration() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    // config

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) {
        oauthServer.passwordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder)
                .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

My resource server looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private TokenStore tokenStore;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
            http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/roles/**").hasRole("INTERNAL")
            .antMatchers("/priveleges/**").hasRole("INTERNAL")
            .antMatchers("/gameSync/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "INTERNAL")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/oauth/token").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v3/**", "/v2/api-docs", "/configuration/**", "/swagger*/**", "/webjars/**", "/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
        //@formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler();
    }
}
```

The security config therefore is pretty basic since the resource server defines most things:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://springdoc.org/#spring-security-support) on `springdoc-openapi` java library documentation, for a project that uses `spring-security`, you should add the `springdoc-openapi-security` dependency.

In that way `swagger-ui` will render also the *oauth* endpoints:

[image]

In addition, if you want to hide certain paths, you could use the `springdoc.paths-to-exclude` property, documented [here](https://springdoc.org/#springdoc-openapi-core-properties).

Comment: Is merely adding the springdoc-openapi-security enough or should we also define some annotations? If your answer could include that, it would be very helpful.